# how to get data from an array in php

Tags: codeigniter

I have a query like this :

```
    $this->db->select('shop_users.user_id');
    $this->db->select('users.*');
    $this->db->from('shop_users');
    $this->db->join('users' , 'users.id = shop_users.user_id' );
    $this->db->where('shop_users.shop_id',$gets['shop_id']);
    $user = $this->db->get()->result();

    $data['user'] = $user;

    var_dump($user);

    return;
```

content of `var_dump()` is :

```
> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#76 (29) { ["user_id"]=> string(5)
> "33691" ["id"]=> string(5) "33691" ["username"]=> string(16)
> "" ["password"]=> string(32)
> "" ["name"]=> string(8) "Ø³ÙˆØ¯Ù‡"
> ["family"]=> string(17) "Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ú©Ø§Ø´ÛŒ" ["email"]=> string(21)
> "" ["avatar"]=> string(11) "default.gif"
> ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["submit_date"]=> string(19) "2015-12-26
> 13:17:20" ["last_activity"]=> string(1) "0" ["activecode"]=> string(1)
> "0" ["submit_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(1) "1" ["zone"]=>
> string(1) "0" ["city_name"]=> string(1) " " ["phone"]=> string(20)
> "" ["bankAcount"]=> string(13) ""
> ["bankCart"]=> string(1) " " ["bank"]=> string(1) " " ["admin_seen"]=>
> string(1) "1" ["gender"]=> string(1) " " ["finance"]=> string(1) "0"
> ["coupons"]=> string(1) "0" ["shaba"]=> string(1) " " ["ref"]=>
> string(1) "0" ["done"]=> string(1) "0" ["hasmobile"]=> string(1) "0" }
> }
```

now, how can I fetch `user_id` ?

I've test below codes but them return null:

```
$user->user_id;
$user['user_id'];
```

Comment: Use echo "<pre>";  print_r($user); for formatted output instead of using var_dump().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user[0]['user_id'];
```

or

```
$user[0]->user_id;
```

You have to access to first element of your array because it is your array of returned values. (array in array)

Comment: What happened when no data returned i mean no output for query? table empty?  Undefined error occured.

Comment: So then add a IF for array size :) if (empty($user[0])){echo 'empty array';}

Answer (score 1):

You get a array from this query. You can get first item at frist and than get attrs of the item.

```
if($user && count($user)>0){
  echo $user[0]->user_id;
}
```